# Does the use of $\delta(\omega-\omega_1)$ for retrieving amplitude of a single Fourier-component of a periodic function violate Fubuni's requirements?

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, dirac-delta, periodic-functions

I've got a non-negative function $f(x)=a+b\cos(\omega_1 x)$ for $a,b,\omega_1 \in \mathbb R$ and I need to represent $b^2$ as a square of the Fourier-transform of a whatever function.
As a physicist I do my best first without (very much) checking if the transformations are equivalent:
\begin{align}
b&={\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}(\omega)}\vert_{\omega=\omega_1}\tag{1}\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}\delta(\omega-\omega_1)d\omega\tag{2}\\\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}\mathscr{F}\{e^{-i\omega_1 x}\}d\omega\tag{3}\\\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathscr{F}\{f(x)*e^{-i\omega_1 x}\}d\omega\tag{4}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(-i \omega_{1}\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\right) d \omega\tag{5}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\right) d \omega\tag{6}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\right) d \omega\tag{7}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i (\omega-\omega_{1}) x\right) d x\right) d \omega\tag{8}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \left(i\left(\omega-\omega_{1}\right) x\right) d x\right)\right) d \omega\tag{9}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \left(i\left(\omega-\omega_{1}\right) x\right) d x\right) d \omega\tag{10}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \left(i\left(\omega-\omega_{1}\right) x\right) d \omega\right) d x\tag{11}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \iint_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp (i \omega x) \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right) d \omega d x\tag{12}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e x p\left(-i \omega_{1} x\right) d \omega\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\tag{13}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right) d \omega\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\tag{14}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\left[f(x) * \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right)\right](x)} d \omega\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\tag{15}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[f(x) * \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right)\right](x)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d \omega\right) \exp (i \omega x) d x\tag{16}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \mathcal{F}\left\{\left[f(x) * \exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right)\right](x)\right\}(\omega) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d \omega\tag{17}\\\\
\end{align}
Where the last factor is the overall volume of the reciprocal to $x$ space. This quantity has a prefactor of $2\pi$ and units of those inverse to $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx$.

From (6) to (7) was used, that $\exp \left(-i \omega_{1} x\right)$ is not a function of $x'$; from (8) to (9) - that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x^{\prime}\right) \exp \left(i \omega_{1} x^{\prime}\right) d x^{\prime}$ doesn't depend on $x, x'$ and $\omega$; throughout (10)-(12) - the Fubini's (or Fubini-Tonelli's?) theorem is applied; from (12) to (13) the action is performed as, for example, [here in the proof of the multiplication theorem](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html).

My questions are

1. Can either of Fubini's or Fubini-Tonelli's theorems be applied where they are applied in this derivation?
2. Are all the transformations legit (and in which sense)?

My fear is, that either the integrability of $\exp \left(i\left(\omega-\omega_{1}\right) x\right)$ is not met here, or, possibly, other requirements. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The last step doesn't make sense. Up to the last equality you have a number, but in the last term you take the Fourier transform of a number. One can only take the Fourier transform of a function (or a distribution), and then you get a function.

Comment: Why do you want $b$ written as a Fourier transform?

Comment: @md2perpe, I'm sorry I don't understand why the Fourier transform of a function equal to a number (constant function) can't be taken. I want $b$ in a transform form, because by this I hope to apply another theoretical treatment to my physical problem, namely I'd like to use Wiener–Khinchin the next step.

Comment: You can take the Fourier transform of a constant function, but the result will be a Dirac $\delta$, not a number.

Comment: @md2perpe, the result will be something like $b\delta(\omega-\omega_1)$, which is nonsense, since Dirac $\delta$ is not under the integral, right? Does this mean, that the last equality is incorrect and neither of the requirements of Fubini's and Tonelli's theorems are satisfied?

Comment: It's rather that $c \, \delta(\omega-\omega_1)$ is a function-like thing, not a plain value as you want $b$ to be. And since the last equality doesn't make sense, since the left and right things are different kinds of objects, I wouldn't even talk about the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: Have you tried to write the last two steps with the Fourier transform expanded into an integral? Do it!

Comment: @md2perpe, I got it, thanks! I think I have to edit my question, because it is not stated properly. This will take, however, some time, since what I got in the pre-last step is $$\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}[f(x)*e^{-i\omega_1 x}](x)e^{i\omega x}dx\right)d\omega$$ and I don't know now in the moment, how to proceed towards what I need...

Comment: @md2perpe , I revised the stuff according to what you've pointed out. Would you say everything is fine with the question itself now?

Comment: Many of the integrals are not defined/convergent as integrals, but might have an interpretation in the space of distributions.